# How to convert bigint[] field from postgres into class field with a jOOQ gradle plugin

Tags: java, postgresql, gradle, jdbc, jooq

Good day all who interested :) I have some problem with jOOQ. 
I need to generate jOOQ entities from PostgreSQL table. It has a field with `bigint[]` type. jOOQ Gradle plugin(I'm using this one https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin) doesn't have supports of array DateType, so the only way is to use custom types with forced types

```
// jooq config in build.gradle
customTypes {
    customType {
        name = "BigintArrayBinder"
        type = "Long[]"
        converter = "ru.stdev.tskad.yandexnavigator.binder.BigintArrayBinder"
    }
}
forcedTypes {
    forcedType {
        name = "BigintArrayBinder"
        includeExpression = '.*'
        includeTypes = 'ARRAY'
    }
}
```

And this is the implementation of this binder with its converter

```java
public class BigintArrayConverter implements Converter<Object[], Long[]> {

    @Override
    public Long[] from(Object[] t) {
        return t == null ? new Long[]{} : (Long[]) t;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] to(Long[] u) {
        return u == null || u.length == 0 ? new Object[]{} : u;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Object[]> fromType() {
        return Object[].class;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Long[]> toType() {
        return Long[].class;
    }

}
```

```java
import org.jooq.*;
import org.jooq.conf.ParamType;
import org.jooq.impl.DSL;
import org.postgresql.core.BaseConnection;
import org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class BigintArrayBinder implements Binding<Object[], Long[]> {

    // The converter does all the work
    @Override
    public Converter<Object[], Long[]> converter() {
        return new BigintArrayConverter();
    }

    // Rending a bind variable for the binding context's value and casting it to the json type
    @Override
    public void sql(BindingSQLContext<Long[]> ctx) throws SQLException {
        // Depending on how you generate your SQL, you may need to explicitly distinguish
        // between jOOQ generating bind variables or inlined literals.
        if (ctx.render().paramType() == ParamType.INLINED)
            ctx.render().visit(DSL.inline(ctx.convert(converter()).value())).sql("::bigint[]");
        else
            ctx.render().sql("::bigint[]");
    }

    // Registering ARRAY types for JDBC CallableStatement OUT parameters
    @Override
    public void register(BindingRegisterContext<Long[]> ctx) throws SQLException {
        ctx.statement().registerOutParameter(ctx.index(), Types.ARRAY);
    }

    // Converting the Long[] to a bigint[] value and setting that on a JDBC PreparedStatement
    @Override
    public void set(BindingSetStatementContext<Long[]> ctx) throws SQLException {
        Object[] value = ctx.convert(converter()).value();

        BaseConnection connection = (BaseConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/m4",
                "postgres",
                "postgres"
        );

        int longOid = 20;

        System.out.print("value -> ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(value));

        PgArray pgArray = new PgArray(connection, longOid, Arrays.toString(value));

        ctx.statement().setArray(ctx.index(), pgArray);
    }

    // Getting a bigint[] value from a JDBC ResultSet and converting that to a Long[]
    @Override
    public void get(BindingGetResultSetContext<Long[]> ctx) throws SQLException {
        Object[] array = (Object[]) ctx.resultSet().getArray(ctx.index()).getArray();

        ctx.convert(converter()).value(array);
    }

    // Getting a bigint[] value from a JDBC CallableStatement and converting that to a Long[]
    @Override
    public void get(BindingGetStatementContext<Long[]> ctx) throws SQLException {
        Object[] array = (Object[]) ctx.statement().getArray(ctx.index()).getArray();
        ctx.convert(converter()).value(array);
    }

    // Setting a value on a JDBC SQLOutput (useful for Oracle OBJECT types)
    @Override
    public void set(BindingSetSQLOutputContext<Long[]> ctx) throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
    }

    // Getting a value from a JDBC SQLInput (useful for Oracle OBJECT types)
    @Override
    public void get(BindingGetSQLInputContext<Long[]> ctx) throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
    }

}
```

So, it's compiling and worked fine for selects queries. But if I try to make insert I have this exception

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [null]; Error while writing value at JDBC bind index: 7
    at org.jooq_3.13.1.POSTGRES.debug(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:2751)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractBindContext.bindValue(AbstractBindContext.java:127)
    at org.jooq.impl.Val.accept(Val.java:103)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractBindContext.bindInternal(AbstractBindContext.java:269)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractBindContext.visit0(AbstractBindContext.java:88)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit0(AbstractContext.java:457)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:218)
    at org.jooq.impl.QueryPartList.accept(QueryPartList.java:121)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractBindContext.bindInternal(AbstractBindContext.java:269)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractBindContext.visit0(AbstractBindContext.java:88)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit0(AbstractContext.java:457)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractContext.visit(AbstractContext.java:218)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:367)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDelegatingQuery.execute(AbstractDelegatingQuery.java:119)
    at ru.stdev.tskad.yandexnavigator.repository.NavigatorRepository$testInsert$2.invokeSuspend(NavigatorRepository.kt:37)
    at ru.stdev.tskad.yandexnavigator.repository.NavigatorRepository$testInsert$2.invoke(NavigatorRepository.kt)
    at ru.stdev.utp.common.jooq.DefaultJooqWrapper$launchOperation$1.invokeSuspend(DefaultJooqWrapper.kt:17)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:330)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:26)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:109)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:158)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:58)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at ru.stdev.utp.common.jooq.DefaultJooqWrapper.launchOperation(DefaultJooqWrapper.kt:16)
    at ru.stdev.utp.common.jooq.DefaultJooqWrapper.request(DefaultJooqWrapper.kt:27)
    at ru.stdev.tskad.yandexnavigator.repository.NavigatorRepository.testInsert(NavigatorRepository.kt:25)
    at ru.stdev.tskad.yandexnavigator.routes.NavigatorRouteKt$navigator$1.invokeSuspend(NavigatorRoute.kt:23)
    at ru.stdev.tskad.yandexnavigator.routes.NavigatorRouteKt$navigator$1.invoke(NavigatorRoute.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:318)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:163)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute(PipelineContext.kt:183)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:27)
    at io.ktor.routing.Routing.executeResult(Routing.kt:147)
    at io.ktor.routing.Routing.interceptor(Routing.kt:34)
    at io.ktor.routing.Routing$Feature$install$1.invokeSuspend(Routing.kt:99)
    at io.ktor.routing.Routing$Feature$install$1.invoke(Routing.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:318)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:163)
    at io.ktor.features.ContentNegotiation$Feature$install$1.invokeSuspend(ContentNegotiation.kt:107)
    at io.ktor.features.ContentNegotiation$Feature$install$1.invoke(ContentNegotiation.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:318)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:163)
    at io.ktor.features.StatusPages$interceptCall$2.invokeSuspend(StatusPages.kt:101)
    at io.ktor.features.StatusPages$interceptCall$2.invoke(StatusPages.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:91)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScopeKt.coroutineScope(CoroutineScope.kt:194)
    at io.ktor.features.StatusPages.interceptCall(StatusPages.kt:100)
    at io.ktor.features.StatusPages$Feature$install$2.invokeSuspend(StatusPages.kt:140)
    at io.ktor.features.StatusPages$Feature$install$2.invoke(StatusPages.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:318)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:163)
    at io.ktor.features.CallLogging$Feature$install$2.invokeSuspend(CallLogging.kt:139)
    at io.ktor.features.CallLogging$Feature$install$2.invoke(CallLogging.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:318)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:163)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute(PipelineContext.kt:183)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:27)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.DefaultEnginePipelineKt$defaultEnginePipeline$2.invokeSuspend(DefaultEnginePipeline.kt:120)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.DefaultEnginePipelineKt$defaultEnginePipeline$2.invoke(DefaultEnginePipeline.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:318)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:163)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute(PipelineContext.kt:183)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:27)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationCallHandler$handleRequest$1.invokeSuspend(NettyApplicationCallHandler.kt:40)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationCallHandler$handleRequest$1.invoke(NettyApplicationCallHandler.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startCoroutineUndispatched(Undispatched.kt:55)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:111)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:158)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationCallHandler.handleRequest(NettyApplicationCallHandler.kt:30)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationCallHandler.channelRead(NettyApplicationCallHandler.kt:24)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:377)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$600(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:59)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$7.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:368)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error while writing value at JDBC bind index: 7
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBindContext.bindValue0(DefaultBindContext.java:67)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractBindContext.bindValue(AbstractBindContext.java:124)
    ... 81 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 63 out of bounds for length 63
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray.buildArrayList(PgArray.java:450)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray.getBaseTypeName(PgArray.java:811)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setArray(PgPreparedStatement.java:1098)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setArray(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.setArray(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:239)
    at ru.stdev.tskad.yandexnavigator.binder.BigintArrayBinder.set(BigintArrayBinder.java:63)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBindContext.bindValue0(DefaultBindContext.java:62)
    ... 82 common frames omitted
```

The first thing that confuses me it's necessary to create `BaseConnection`. I can get a connection from DslContext, but it returns a `HikariProxyConnection`. So, it's not applying to `PgArray`, it requires `BaseConnection`. Then, I need to give it an `oid`, that equals 20 to Long type. And then i have to give a array as string or byte array. And as result i have `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I made many attempts to find decision of this problem, but i failed. What i do wrong? I feel like I'm doing something wrong, but I don't understand what exactly.

Comment: What's the column data type you have in the postgres db?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli bigint[]

Comment: And what do you get generated by jooq if you don't configure anything?

Comment: I got Stackoverflow error with this stack trace: `java.lang.StackOverflowError at org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator.getType(JavaGenerator.java:6477)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [Connection.createArrayOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createArrayOf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29)

Eg `ctx.statement().getConnection().createArrayOf(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this?

```
BaseConnection connection = (BaseConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/m4",
                "postgres",
                "postgres"
        );
```

You should already have a connection by this time. Since you never close this connection you likely have a resource leak here.

You can probably do

```
BaseConnection connection = (BaseConnection)  ctx.statement().getConnection()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried this one. And in the runtime I got an exception: `ClassCastException: class com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection cannot be cast to class org.postgresql.core.BaseConnection`

Comment: but the direction is right, I trying to find a solution for this case too. 
jOOQ is started on Netty(Ktor framework), and `DriverManager` is a temporary decision. I want to have a working solution with `bigint[]` DB type in my code, this task have high priority.

Answer (score 0):

The code solution:

```java
public class BigintArrayBinder implements Binding<Object[], Long[]> {

    // The converter does all the work
    @Override
    public Converter<Object[], Long[]> converter() {
        return new BigintArrayConverter();
    }

    // Rending a bind variable for the binding context's value and casting it to the bigint array type
    @Override
    public void sql(BindingSQLContext<Long[]> ctx) throws SQLException {
        ctx.render().visit(DSL.inline(ctx.convert(converter()).value()));
    }

    // Registering ARRAY types for JDBC CallableStatement OUT parameters
    @Override
    public void register(BindingRegisterContext<Long[]> ctx) throws SQLException {
        ctx.statement().registerOutParameter(ctx.index(), Types.ARRAY);
    }

    // Converting the Long[] to a bigint[] value and setting that on a JDBC PreparedStatement
    @Override
    public void set(BindingSetStatementContext<Long[]> ctx) {
        Object[] value = ctx.convert(converter()).value();

        ctx.dsl().connection(connection -> connection.createArrayOf("bigint", value));
    }

    // Getting a bigint[] value from a JDBC ResultSet and converting that to a Long[]
    @Override
    public void get(BindingGetResultSetContext<Long[]> ctx) throws SQLException {
        Object[] array = (Object[]) ctx.resultSet().getArray(ctx.index()).getArray();

        ctx.convert(converter()).value(array);
    }

    // Getting a bigint[] value from a JDBC CallableStatement and converting that to a Long[]
    @Override
    public void get(BindingGetStatementContext<Long[]> ctx) throws SQLException {
        Object[] array = (Object[]) ctx.statement().getArray(ctx.index()).getArray();
        ctx.convert(converter()).value(array);
    }

    // Setting a value on a JDBC SQLOutput (useful for Oracle OBJECT types)
    @Override
    public void set(BindingSetSQLOutputContext<Long[]> ctx) throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
    }

    // Getting a value from a JDBC SQLInput (useful for Oracle OBJECT types)
    @Override
    public void get(BindingGetSQLInputContext<Long[]> ctx) throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
    }

}
```